# Error in the.map$names : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, tidyverse, cluster-computing, purrr

I am working on the following code to produce some clusters

```
#Grouping pupils as per their performance at two intermediate examinations----
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(cluster)
student <- read_csv("clustering-student-mat.csv") #In workspace
#student
K <- 2:8
list_clu_res <- vector("list", length(K))

list_clu_res <- map(K, ~kmeans(student %>% select(Exam1, Exam2), centers = .))
for(i in seq_along(K)) {
  student_clu <- student %>%
    bind_cols(tibble(cluster = list_clu_res[[i]]$cluster)) %>%
    mutate(cluster = factor(cluster))
  # Filter points that lie on a cluster's convex hull
  student_hull <- student_clu %>%
    split(.$cluster) %>%
    map(~ slice(., chull(.$Exam1, .$Exam2))) %>%
    do.call("rbind", .)
  print(ggplot(student_clu, aes(Exam1, Exam2, color = cluster, fill = cluster)) +
          geom_polygon(data = student_hull, alpha = .5, color = "black") +
          geom_point(pch = 21) +
          geom_point(data = student_clu %>%
                       group_by(cluster) %>%
                       summarize_all(mean), shape = "+", color = "black",
                     size = 8) +
          guides(fill = FALSE, color = FALSE) +
          labs(title = str_c("k=", K[i])))
}
```

But when I invoked the `map()` it gives the following error:

```
Error in the.map$names : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

The code worked few days back but now when I am running again it gives this error.

Data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2rxm0hhpkh2sv2/clustering-student-mat.csv?dl=0)

Any help is appreciated to fix the code.